# I am a little bit confused about what they mean by the following...

Tags: linear-algebra

I read:

> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T \in L(V,W)$. Prove
> that there exists a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with respect to
> these bases all entries of $M(T)$ are $0$ except that the entries in row $j$,
> column $j$, equal $1$ for $j\leq 1\leq \dim \operatorname{range}(T)$.

Here $M(T)$ denotes the matrix of linear the map $T$.

What do they mean by this? Do they mean that the $j$th column and $j$th row are all zeros or that if the column equals the row then it's a one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnDouma I am so sorry what do I need to clarify? Should I just type the whole question

Comment: Consider a function on a three dimensional space whose range is two dimensions. This will be like the identity but the last element on the diagonal will be zero. Does that make sense? What if the range of a $4\times 4$ was one dimension?

Comment: @john douma Yeah I thought so but wasn't sure also English is not my first language nor my second nor my third It's my Fourth

Comment: @Woody Much respect for knowing that many languages!!

Comment: I understand that. But even non-native speakers should know the basic structure of the language. For example, "what do they mean.." should have $W$ capitalized. Forgive me for being pedantic but I look at lapses in grammar like I do graffiti in the city. It is a sign of decay.

Comment: @Woody Careful - you accepted my answer immediately! Usually on this site it makes sense to wait a bit, read around, before accepting!

Comment: @ John Douma Yeah I could have put more effort in writing this but in my defence I have a very bad headache at the moment.

Comment: There is no need to explain. I am also impressed that this is your fourth language.

Comment: @IdiotShrike Nah I was just a little bit confused an got conformation. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

This is no longer an answer for the question in its current form.

OP:

The matrix has $0$ everywhere except for those entries at row $j$, column $j$. I will suppose that we call the matrix $A$, and a very common notation you should be used to is $A_{m,n}$ which denotes the $m$th row and the $n$th column of the matrix $A$.

With this in mind, in your matrix, $A_{m,n}=1$ when $m=n$: i.e. $A_{j,j}=1$. The range $1\le j\le\dim(range(T))$ just means $j$ is kept within the bounds of a matrix, although whoever wrote this probably made a mistake - they should have said that the matrix is square; also be aware that sometimes $\dim(range(M))$ for some matrix $M$ might be less, even a lot less, than the actual number of rows/columns of that matrix.

Your matrix is the identity matrix. It leaves whatever it is multiplied by unchanged - it is like the number one in that respect. $A\times B=B$ for all $B$ for which the multiplication is actually legal.

It looks like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\dots&0\\0&1&0&\dots&0\\0&0&1&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\0&0&0&\dots&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and can be any size, so long as it is square. If you read $j,j$ you must immediately think of diagonals! This diagonal in particular, the very long one (the longest in any square matrix) is called the *main diagonal*. Any matrix with ones in the *main* diagonal and zeros everywhere else is an *identity* matrix. If it has a different constant along the main diagonal, but still zeros everywhere else, i.e. "it has the constant $k$ on every row $j$, column $j$, and zeros everywhere else", to use the language of the question, then it is a *scaling matrix*. This has the effect $AB=kB$ - it scales $B$.

A common notation for [the identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) is $I$.

I wrote far more than is necessary for a question like this just because I guessed you were new to this subject. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, what?! I think this is much more confusing. For example, if $T \in L(\mathbb R^6, \mathbb R^4)$ has $\dim(\operatorname{range}T)$ equal $3$, then the problem ask to find bases for $\Bbb R^6$ and $\Bbb R^4$ such that the matrix of $T$ in this bases is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: @ azif00 that's correct

Comment: @azif00 the question was in a much simpler state when I answered it; the problem of bases in a certain sub space wasn’t there. The OP asked about what (without context, and in the general look of a beginner’s question, but clearly now OP does not appear beginner) looked like the identity matrix

Comment: @azif00 If you read carefully, I say “they *probably* made a mistake, they *should* have said it was square” because I was left guessing about the nature of the question.

Comment: @Woody since this question is sort of active again, I may as well ask what is meant by $(L,W)$. I have never seen this $L$ before. Does it denote some function space?

Comment: @idioticshrike I don't know how that mistake got there... It was supposed to be that T is an element of all linear maps between V and W.